# What's the arbitrum address for EUROC?

Tags: arbitrum

Here's the address on the ethereum network: https://etherscan.io/token/0x1aBaEA1f7C830bD89Acc67eC4af516284b1bC33c

I would like to know which is the corresponding address in the arbitrum network

Comment: It looks like it's only available on Ethereum at the moment.

https://www.circle.com/en/euro-coin